# Assimilation of "Bind and Loose" with "Teaching Authority" by the Catholic Church

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-matthew, authority, papal-magisterium

This question is somewhat related to another question: [Connections Between "Gates of Hell" and Heresies from a Catholic Standpoint](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/97347/connections-between-gates-of-hell-and-heresies-from-a-catholic-standpoint)

In Fr. William Most's article [*Which Church Saves?*](https://www.ewtn.com/catholicism/library/which-church-saves-12280) he writes (**emphasis** mine):

> But Jesus also said many things. For example: in Matt 18.17: "If he will not hear the church, let him be to you as a heathen and a publican." And Matthew 16.19: "I will give you the keys of the kingdom of heaven, and whatsoever you bind on earth shall be bound in heaven, and whatever you loose on earth shall be loosed in heaven." **In the language of the time, to bind and loose meant to give authoritative teaching.**

QUESTION: Can someone elaborate (perhaps with some references) on Fr. Most's conclusion: "In the language of the time, to bind and loose meant to give authoritative teaching" ?

I am interested in the historical assimilation of *"bind and loose"* with *"teaching authority"* by the Catholic Church.

Comment: Of interest.  https://www.gotquestions.org/binding-loosing.html